# Proving asymptotic estimation of a sum

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I have been looking at some solutions to a differential equations and I observed the following asymptotic, but I'm struggling to prove this:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(x - nr)^n}{n!} H(x - nr) \sim \frac{1}{W(r) + 1} \exp \left (\frac{W(r)}{r}x \right )
\end{align*}
as $x \to \infty$, where $H$ is the Heaviside Function and $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function (i.e. $xe^x = r \implies x = W(r)$).

The specific equation is solving $y'(x) = y(x - r)$, and the left hand side comes from solving this for $x \geq 0$ with $y$ continuous and $y(x) = 1$ for $0 \leq x \leq r$, and it isn't too difficult to see why this implies $f(x) \sim C \exp \left (\frac{W(r)}{r}x \right )$, but I haven't had any luck proving $C = \frac{1}{W(r) + 1}$.

Any solutions would be great.

Comment: Just out of curiosity : how did you find the rhs (even without any proof) ?

Comment: Find $F(s) = \mathcal L[y](s)$ and show that $\mathcal L^{-1}[F](x)$ is asymptotically equivalent to the value of the residue of $F(s) e^{x s}$ at the rightmost pole of $F$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Solving the DE for an analytic solution yields the form the RHS is in. I determined the constant form by substituting $r = 1$ and using Mathematica to get the value of the constant to 50 decimal places, then putting it into WA for a possible closed form. I then generalised to arbitrary $r$.

Comment: @Maxim Could you elaborate on your method? I'm not sure how to deal with the incomplete gamma function you get from taking the Laplace transform.

Comment: speaking of Laplace transforms, i would try to replace $(x-nr)^n/n!$ in your sum by an appropriate Inverse Laplace transform and then exchange intergration and summation (which will be a simple geometric one). Afterwards we pick up residues in the correct halfplane and only have to determine which is the dominant one (no incomplete gammas with this approach)

Comment: Apply the Laplace transform to the DDE, not to the sum. Since $y$ can be taken to be zero on $(-\infty, 0)$ (because of the choice of the initial condition) and is continuous and piecewise smooth on $(0, \infty)$, we can use the standard properties of the LT.

Comment: @asgeige I realised that my function could be written a bit more cleanly so as to avoid having an $x$ term in the limits by using the Heaviside function, but now I'm not sure how to deal with taking inverse Laplace transform of something with Heaviside function involved - not even sure this is well defined since inverse Laplace transform of Dirac delta does not exist.

Comment: the heaviside is good:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=InverseLaplaceTransform%5BExp%5B+-r+n+s%5D%2Fs%5E%28n%2B1%29+%2Cs%2C+t%5D is the relation i was thinking about

Comment: The sum in question is (we assume $x,r>0$ troughout) 
$$
f_r(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(x - nr)^n}{n!} H(x - nr)
$$

this equals by a standard inverse Laplace transform ($\gamma >0$)

$$
f_r(x) = \frac1{2 \pi i}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \int_{\gamma-i \infty}^{\gamma+i \infty}ds e^{xs}\frac{e^{-rns}}{s^{n+1}}
$$

note that due the lack of singularities we can pull our contour as far to the right as we like until we have that  $|\exp(- r s)/s|<1$ so that $\sum_n \frac{e^{-rns}}{s^{n+1}}$ converges absolutly

Comment: and we can safely exchange sum and integral. That said we arrive at (using simple geometric series)

$$
f_r(x) = \int_{\gamma-i \infty}^{\gamma+i \infty}ds \underbrace{\frac{e^{(x+r)s}}{se^{rs}-1}}_{g_r(s,x)}
$$

the rest of the calculation is now just a matter of calculating residues (we close the contour to the left to ensure convergence)

$$
f_r(x)=\sum_{k \in Z}\text{res}(g_r(s,x),s=\tfrac{W_k(r)}r) \quad (1)
$$ 

where $\tfrac{W_k(r)}r$ solves $s e^{rs}=1$ (the Lambert W function).

Since the poles of $g_r(x,s)$ are simple, the residues are easy to calculate:

Comment: $$
\text{res}(g_r(s,x),s=\tfrac{W_k(r)}r)=\frac{e^{x W_k(r)/r}}{W_k(r)+1}
$$

Using the Lemma at the end of the post, we can conclude that the dominating contribution to  $(1)$ is provided by the purely real $0$-branch part. We obtain

>$$
f_r(x)\sim \frac{e^{x W_0(r)/r}}{W_0(r)+1}
$$

as expected

Comment: Lemma :
$$
\Re W_0 > \Re W_i,\quad i\neq0
$$

Proof:

We know that for $r>0$, $W_0$ is the only purely real branch of Lambert-W function.
Now consider
$$
we^w=r
$$

taking absolute values, this yields

$$
r=|w|e^{\Re w}
$$

let be $w_1$ be a purely real solution and $w_2$ (clearly bigger then 0) one with finite imaginary part. We get the relation

Comment: $$
w_1 e^{w_1}=e^{\Re w_2}\sqrt{(\Re w_2)^2+(\Im w_2)^2}
$$
clearly $w_1=\Re w_2$ is impossible. Now we assume $\Re w_2>w_1$. This would imply that

$$
w_1e^{w_1-\Re w_2}>\sqrt{w_1^2+(\Im w_2)^2}
$$

which is false, since the lhs is smaller then $w_1$ and the rhs is greater then $w_1$. 

QED

Comment: i leave that as a comment, since i don't have the time to clean thisup properly

Comment: Now it's time for moderators to "clean this up" ;)

Comment: @asgeige Thanks for the solution, I would give you the bounty if I could :P